# Printing a text file as a dictionary python

Tags: python, file, dictionary

Text file I am working on

```
3:d:10:i:30
1:d:10:i:15
4:r:30
1:r:15
2:d:12:r:8
4:l:20
5:i:15
3:l:20:r:22
4:d:30
5:l:15:r:15
```

I am trying to print a dictionary from a text file that should come out looking like :

```
{1: {'d': 10, 'i': 15, 'r': 15},
2: {'d': 12, 'r': 8},
3: {'d': 10, 'i': 30, 'l': 20, 'r': 22},
4: {'d': 30, 'l': 20, 'r': 30},
5: { 'i': 15, 'l': 15, 'r': 15}}
```

Instead my code is overiding each line in the file and only takes the most recent line as the value in the dictionary so it looks like:

```
 {'3': {'l': '20', 'r': '22'}, 
 '1': {'r': '15'}, 
 '4': {'d': '30'}, 
 '2': {'d': '12', 'r': '8'}, 
 '5': {'l': '15', 'r': '15'}})
```

This is what I have so far

```
def read_db(file):
d = defaultdict(dict)
for line in open('db1.txt'):
    z = line.rstrip().split(':')
    d[z[0]]=dict( zip(z[1::2],z[2::2]))
print(d)
```

I tried doing += but that operand is not working on the dict. I am a bit stuck. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach using a simple iteration and `dict.setdefault`.

**Ex:**

```
res = {}
with open(filename) as infile:           #Open file to read
    for line in infile:                  #Iterate Each line 
        line = line.strip().split(":")   #Split by colon
        res.setdefault(line.pop(0), {}).update(dict(zip(line[::2], line[1::2])))    

print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
{'1': {'d': '10', 'i': '15', 'r': '15'},
 '2': {'d': '12', 'r': '8'},
 '3': {'d': '10', 'i': '30', 'l': '20', 'r': '22'},
 '4': {'d': '30', 'l': '20', 'r': '30'},
 '5': {'i': '15', 'l': '15', 'r': '15'}}
```

---

Or using `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict
res = defaultdict(dict)
with open(filename) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip().split(":")
        res[line.pop(0)].update(dict(zip(line[::2], line[1::2])))

print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>,
            {'1': {'d': '10', 'i': '15', 'r': '15'},
             '2': {'d': '12', 'r': '8'},
             '3': {'d': '10', 'i': '30', 'l': '20', 'r': '22'},
             '4': {'d': '30', 'l': '20', 'r': '30'},
             '5': {'i': '15', 'l': '15', 'r': '15'}})
```